# Python script for insert data from list to mysql data base table

Tags: python

I have data in list,I want to insert in a database table along with auto increment id ,Please help me in writing python script for that.

Thanks,
Sharmila

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: what help you need what errors you are getting now?

Comment: So show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this :

```
len = len(some_list)
for i in rang(len):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO my_table(id, item) VALUES (?, ?)", (i, some_list[i]))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: for x in some_list:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO mylist(item) VALUES(%s)", (x,))
conn.commit()

Comment: this is working                                                                                       Thank you